# STM32F4 DMA UART

Tags: uart, dma, stm32f4

I'm using STM32F401RE UART with DMA to receive a continuous stream of data and send over BLE. I am using buffer of size 20 or 1023 bytes. I am facing issue  that DMA buffer full interrupt stops working as it start receiving data continuously. 
It works perfectly fine when I send data in chunks (20 or 1023 bytes) through PC COM port in non-continuous manner. I am trying to work in debugger mode and it works with PC COM port setup and hits breakpoints in DMA callback function but not on stream of data.
I check the data streaming module its working fine.

Program is getting into  "HAL_UART_ErrorCallback" function and I am reactivating "HAL_UART_Receive_DMA" but still not resolving the issue.

Kindly let me know how to resolve the issue.

Many many thanks.

Kind Regards,
Ghalib

Comment: Use circular mode and handle data by timer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue got resolved, noise was causing issue on UART signals.